# jmeter.extractor.RegexExtractor: Error in pattern

Tags: regex, jmeter

I tested my regex in the tree view and it worked fine, but when I actually run the test it's giving me the error in the title.

The pattern I'm using is `(?<=\{\"id\":)\d+`

I have also tried `(?<=\{\"id\":)(\d+)`

The response data looks like this: `aaData":[{"id":488,"environment":` (I am trying to match `488`)

I've tried changing the response field to check (I've tried them all), not sure what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your regular expression itself is OK.

At a pinch (not having used jmeter) I'd say the problem is with the lack of support for lookbehinds.

In the current [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) it is states:

> Note that (?<=regexp) - lookbehind - is not supported.

I guess `\{\"id\":(\d+)` should work without upset (provided you're able to use the first capture group as a result.

Edit The working regex ended up using a non capturing group:

```
(?:\{\"id\":)(\d+)
```

Comment: You're probably right. And while you're at it, the curly braces and quotes don't have to be escaped (the quotes may have to be, depending on the string delimiter for the regex itself): `{"id":(\d+)`

Comment: I think you're correct, I wasn't sure if jmeter had any special behaviour and erred on the side of caution.

Comment: I was under the impression that the regex tester under the `View Results Tree` was processed the same way the extractor would be processed. Any ideas why it would work fine in the tester, but not in the extractor?

Comment: Very good question, I'm not familiar enough with jmeter to give a good answer, might be worth trying a really simple lookbehind to verify that's the case. Someone with more knowledge may drop in with an answer =D

Comment: @BrianStephens Your regex gives me `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition`

@Chris Your regex appears to match the entire thing... I just want the number

Comment: Try wrapping the first part in a non-capturing group (provided they're supported). So something along the lines of `(?:\{\"id\":)(\d+)`

Comment: Or use the group matched by `(\d+)` - that's why it's in parens.

Comment: @Chris That appears to have worked, thank you! Could you update your answer with the non-capturing group?